# Pandas 0.21.1 - DataFrame.replace recursion error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I was used to run this code with no issue:

```
data_0 = data_0.replace([-1, 'NULL'], [None, None])
```

now, after the update to Pandas 0.21.1, with the very same line of code I get a:

> recursionerror: maximum recursion depth exceeded

does anybody experience the same issue ? and knows how to solve ?

Note: rolling back to pandas 0.20.3 will make the trick but I think it's important to solve with latest version

thanx

Comment: Try using a dict: `data_0.replace(dict.fromkeys([-1, 'NULL']))`

Comment: same error (and thanx anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I think this error message depends on what your input data is. Here's an example of input data where this works in the expected way:

```
data_0 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [-1, 1], 'y': ['NULL', 'foo']})
data_0.replace([-1, 'NULL'], [None, None])
```

replaces values of `-1` and `'NULL'` with None:

```
    x     y
0  NaN  None
1  1.0   foo
```