# maximum recursion depth exceeded - ProfileReport & sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to connect to db; access tables; do data profiling but keep on getting the maximum recursion error. I can upload csv and run the profilers individually. What's my mistake in terms of fetching the data?
Code:

```
#importing libraries
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
import numpy as np
import time

# Create an engine to the census database
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://{dbname}:{password}@{string}/{dbname}')

# Print the table names
lst = engine.table_names()

for x in lst:
    time.sleep(60)#sleep for 60 seconds 
    df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM '''+x, engine)
    report = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df,correlation_threshold=1)
    report.to_file(x + ".html")
```

Error I am getting:

````
<ipython-input-16-5845b8468e3b> in <module>()
      5     time.sleep(60)#sleep for 1 second
      6     df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM '''+x, engine)
----> 7     report = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df,correlation_threshold=1)
      8     report.to_file(x + ".html")

C:\Users\katep\Miniconda3\envs\cy_example\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.pyc in __init__(self, df, **kwargs)
     64         sample = kwargs.get('sample', df.head())
     65 
---> 66         description_set = describe_df(df, **kwargs)
     67 
     68         self.html = to_html(sample,

C:\Users\katep\Miniconda3\envs\cy_example\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\describe.pyc in describe(df, bins, check_correlation, correlation_threshold, correlation_overrides, check_recoded, pool_size, **kwargs)
    361         pool = multiprocessing.Pool(pool_size)
    362         local_multiprocess_func = partial(multiprocess_func, **kwargs)
--> 363         ldesc = {col: s for col, s in pool.map(local_multiprocess_func, df.iteritems())}
    364         pool.close()
    365 

C:\Users\katep\Miniconda3\envs\cy_example\lib\multiprocessing\pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    251         '''
    252         assert self._state == RUN
--> 253         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    254 
    255     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):

C:\Users\katep\Miniconda3\envs\cy_example\lib\multiprocessing\pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
    570             return self._value
    571         else:
--> 572             raise self._value
    573 
    574     def _set(self, i, obj):

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded```
````

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, updated.

Comment: Have you checked [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/84) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791164/pandas-0-21-1-dataframe-replace-recursion-error) ? Not duplicates but could shed some light on the source

Comment: Do you mean to roll back to pandas N?

Comment: @calestini, you are genius! Rolling back to pandas N worked! Loopig through the tables and getting my profiles.